# mysql_query sorting with WHERE=$var

Tags: mysql, sorting

This might be a duplicate. Wasn't sure what to search for so I didn't find anything.

```
$get_feed_p=mysql_query("SELECT followed FROM follow WHERE user='$_COOKIE[PC_ID]'");
while($feed_p=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_feed_p)){
    $get_feed=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status WHERE to_user='$feed_p[followed]' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
}
```

So first query selects followed profiles (Like on twitter)
Second one selects status updates.

The problem I have is with ordering. Because I use WHERE to_user=$feed_p[followed] all the statuses are sorted by user, not the id like I need it to.

How can I sort the rows by id only?

Comment: do you have an users table where we can finde both user and ids ?

Comment: Yes I have but it's not connected to any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have interpreted what you are trying to do correctly (listing all statuses posted by users the logged in user follows and list the by the status id, most recent first?), then you want to do this:

```
$get_feed = mysql_query("SELECT status.* FROM follow
RIGHT JOIN status ON status.to_user = follow.followed
WHERE follow.user = '" . $_COOKIE[PC_ID . "' ORDER BY status.id DESC LIMIT 20")
```

Really hope this was what you were looking for since it's my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a join instead of many selects?
Something like (I'm on my mobile and so couldn't try it, I may have a deeper look during the week end):

```
SELECT
    follow.followed, status.id
FROM
    follow
    LEFT JOIN status ON status.id IN (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            status
        WHERE
            follow.user = status.to_user
        ORDER BY id LIMIT 20 )
WHERE
    followed.user = '$_COOKIE[PC_ID]'
```

Comment: Trying to get this to work but I've rarely used mysql_queries and I'm having problems. Seems I'm not outputting it correctly or the query is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

lets say that the  table that contains the users is user_tbl (user and ids) :

```
"SELECT * FROM status WHERE
 to_user='$feed_p[followed]' ORDER BY
(select id from users_tbl where username='$feed_p[followed]') DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Comment: Wouldn't that directly order by user id again? I need it to be sorted by status id.